# Why is googleapiclient imported by a different name?

Tags: python, import, google-api-python-client

According to `pip freeze`, I have the following module installed:

・google-api-python-client==2.0.2

And as my understanding goes, in order to use this, you need to do one of the following:

- `import google-api-python-client`
- `import google-api-python-client as apiclient`
- `from google-api-python-client import sth`

However all of these give package not found errors, and I have to instead use

- `from apiclient.discovery import build`

Why/How is it possible to `import` it using `apiclient`, without doing
`from google-api-python-client as apiclient` beforehand?

Comment: Without knowing any details about the `googleapiclient`, I can tell you that module name's can't have dash `-` characters in them because they have to be legal Python [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) — so that aspect of your understanding cannot be correct. My guess to why `from apiclient.discovery` works is because `discovery` is a sub-module of the `apiclient` package.

Comment: thanks for the response- yes, so I now realized a problem in my understanding/this question - 'google-api-python-client' is the name of the PACKAGE installed, not module.

Comment: and I have now discovered that package name isn't necessarily equal to the top/main module within that package - so there was no reason to think I should have been importing using the module name.